# Creating an Installation Package That Grabs Python Modules From the Web

Tags: python, windows, installation, iexpress

I am trying to create an installation package for my program that I can send to other people who don't have any programming background and presumably cannot use the command line. The program itself is fairly user friendly, but it requires the installation of several Python packages from the Python Package Index to function. I was able to install these packages with pip (though that did not work for one, so I had to download and manually install it from the .tar.gz), but I don't think my users will be able to do this or troubleshoot installation problems like I did.

My users and I are working in a Windows environment, so I tried using iExpress wizard to create an installation file. But the wizard does not include any options for installing a large number of files in a directory tree format or automatically adding those directories to PATH; so that does not seem to be an option.

What is the simplest approach I can take to automatically and properly install these Python modules for my users?

**EDIT**

I am also considering the possibility of using a batch file included in the installation package, but I would still like to know if there is a more streamlined way of doing this kind of installation.

Comment: Have you thought about including the needed libraries as part of the package you distribute?  (This will depend on license requirements but is often a possibility.)

Comment: That is what I originally tried to do. But iExpress does not allow for the installation of directory trees or the inclusion of said directories within PATH. I want this to be done automatically by the installer.

Comment: Have you looked at things like [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/)?

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, I decided it was simpler to just put all of the source code and directory trees in a ZIP file and give the user careful instructions on how to add those trees to their PATH. Thanks anyway for the help guys.